# How can I export a VirtualBox machine to OVA appliance using Python?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ovf, appliance

I need to create (export) a virtual machine (VirtualBox) to a OVA/OVF appliance.

I tried to use the `IMachine.export_to()` method (through pyvbox wrapper) like this:

```
import virtualbox
from virtualbox.library import ExportOptions


vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
vm = vbox.find_machine(VM_NAME)

appliance = vbox.create_appliance()
p = appliance.write('ovf-2.0',
                    [ExportOptions.create_manifest],
                    '~/tmp/test5.ovf')
desc = slredmine.export_to(appliance, '~/tmp/test5.ovf')
```

The above code doesn't do what I want: no ova/ovf is created.

**UPDATE**

The instructions order was wrong. See my answer written below.

Comment: Reordered the question, and fixed some spelling and grammar issues.  Also, the "ova" tag seems to mean something different to what you thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

```
import virtualbox
from virtualbox.library import ExportOptions

VM_NAME = 'foovmname'    

vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
vm = vbox.find_machine(VM_NAME)

appliance = vbox.create_appliance()
desc = slredmine.export_to(appliance, VM_NAME)
p = appliance.write('ovf-2.0',
                    [ExportOptions.create_manifest],
                    '~/tmp/test5.ovf')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the pyvbox documentation, it can only export to OVF format, but that should not really matter, depending on what you want to do with it.

Documentation quote:

> As with importing, first call IVirtualBox.create_appliance() to create
>   an empty IAppliance object.
>
> For each machine you would like to export, call IMachine.export_to()
>   with the IAppliance object you just created. Each such call creates
>   one instance of IVirtualSystemDescription inside the appliance.
>
> If desired, call IVirtualSystemDescription.set_final_values() for each
>   virtual system (machine) to override the suggestions made by the
>   IMachine.export_to() routine.
>
> Finally, call write() with a path specification to have the OVF file
>   written.

Feel free to share your code if you are stuck.